# rounded diagonal line css

Tags: css, border, css-shapes, diagonal

Please tell me how to make such a diagonal line:

- shape:

[image]

- [**fiddle link**](http://goo.gl/4ynCe) + code:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="block"></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.block {
    margin: 50px auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: black;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

I am looking for information how to do it but did not find.

Comment: look this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-create-diagonal-lines-with-css/

Answer (score 6):

Try 3D transforms - something like this:

## [*demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/q4Yzj/2/)

Relevant **CSS**:

```
body /* parent of .block in general */ {
    -webkit-perspective: 15em;
    perspective: 15em;
}
.block {
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(-5deg) rotateY(10deg);
    transform: rotateX(-5deg) rotateY(10deg);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, almost perfect, but does not work in IE8 and Opera 12.15. Perhaps even within the content? My attempt to align: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ShootingStar/WrQAh/4/)

Comment: @ShootingStar CSS3 is not supported by older browsers. The shape, in that case, needs to be created using images.